# Centering an image with edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to center an image within the screen. It goes should fit the height but stretch the width outside the screen to keep it proportional. The image properly sizes and centers itself normally, but as soon as I add `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` the image gets off-centered. I don't know if this is a bug, but I am just starting up with it SwiftUI so there may be a simple answer.

#### Without `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("background_rain")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: first image]

#### With `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("background_rain")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: second image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you really attached different images, they look same for me? ... and second code works properly with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1, at least with my images.

Comment: the two images are the same

Comment: You can just use `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` with nothing else, it will be centered

Comment: @Asperi second is off [center](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/Screen%20Shot%202020-12-23%20at%208.38.42%20AM.png) for me in Xcode 12.2 / iOS 14.2

Comment: Could you attach original second image, so I test it locally?

Comment: @Asperi I can confirm it's off center in Xcode 12.3 as well. This looks like another bug.

Comment: Sorry, I attached the same image twice. The images should be correct now.

Comment: @Asperi here is the [original image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HTdOdvnY-YsSM0OFE97cDILle5ep0G-p/view?usp=sharing). Tell me if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
    Color.clear.overlay(
      Image("background_rain")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    )
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Why? I had the same problem... black magic.

Comment: Does anyone know why this works?

Answer (score 2):

I also figured this out by setting the `maxWidth` to the screen size

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    Image("background_rain")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```